# JQuery Draggable option

Tags: jquery

Anyone please help me with the below code. The Draggable option is not working. I cannot figure out what is wrong..

```
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#draggableDiv").draggable();
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
 .divClass 
 {
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     background-color:Blue;
     color: White;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     display: table-cell;
 }
 #draggableDiv { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
</style>
</head>
```

Drag me around

Comment: <body>

<div id="draggableDiv" class="divClass">
<p> Drag me around </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#draggableDiv").draggable();
});
```

```css
.divClass {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: Blue;
  color: White;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
}
#draggableDiv {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <!-- include script -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> <!-- include script -->
<div id="draggableDiv" class="divClass">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Maybe you are just missing some `script`. Make sure you have all the script included

Answer (score 0):

you should order jquery scripts like this.

```
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you may find this link for your answer  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/praveentpt/76tk4vzq/)

```
<div id="draggable" class="divClass">
<p>Drag you div</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, may be problem is with script that you included
Check this

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#draggableDiv").draggable();
    });
```

```css
.divClass 
 {
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     background-color:Blue;
     color: White;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
     display: table-cell;
 }
 #draggableDiv { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 
<body> 
  
  <div id="draggableDiv" class="divClass"> <p> Drag me around </p> </div> 
</body>
```